# Require content-type 'application/json' for appropriate requests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-type

I have an API that handles almost exclusively `application/json` in Rails. A few endpoints can handle `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for file-uploads.

I want to enforce the content-types: when a client adds anything other than `application/json` I want to send an 406 - not acccepted error back, in my `ApplicationController`

```
before_action :require_content_type_json

def require_content_type_json
  return if request.content_type == Mime::JSON.to_s
  head status: 406
end
```

However, [RFC 7231 (http)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) states that:

> A sender that generates a message containing a payload body SHOULD
> generate a Content-Type header field in that message unless the
> intended media type of the enclosed representation is unknown to the
> sender.  If a Content-Type header field is not present, the recipient
> MAY either assume a media type of "application/octet-stream"
> ([RFC2046], Section 4.5.1) or examine the data to determine its type.

I roughtly interpret that as "when the request comes with a body, the content-type must be provided by the client, else the server should assume "application/octet-stream".

Since I cannot handle octet-stream, I want to return 406 - not accepted too, there. In other words: when there is a body, a header setting the content-type to "application/json" should be present. Always.

So, how do I detect whether a user should have sent a content-type header along? Is it enough to simply check for `!request.body.empty?`: body is not empty?

Or should I assume that only GET/OPTIONS/HEAD requests have no body and all others do and should require a content-type?

Does Rails have any helpers or classes in place to deal with this?